# getting 504 in Karate Automation

Tags: automation, postman, karate

I am facing 504 gateway time out in karate script but not in postman. I have checked everything including body. I am currently in 1.4.0 version. The post call body is working with other calls and the auth is correct infact I have also passed required headers.

Getting rid of 504 error